# What's eshell's syntax for command substitution?

Tags: eshell

```
for pid in $(ps -ef | grep "chrome" | awk '{print $2}'); do kill -9 $pid; done

Invalid read syntax: ")"
```

What's the right way to run this script in Eshell?

Comment: eshell for loop syntax: [link1](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellForLoop), [link2](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eshell/for-loop.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask Emacs:

- `C-h i` to open info
- `g(eshell)for loop` to open the node on for loops in eshell

or

- `M-x info-display-manual RET eshell RET`
- `gfor loop`

[There it says](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eshell/for-loop.html#for-loop):

> Because Eshell commands can not (easily) be combined with lisp forms,
>   Eshell provides a command-oriented `for'-loop for convenience.  The
>   syntax is as follows:
>
> ```
> `for VAR in TOKENS { command invocation(s) }'
> ```
>
> where TOKENS is a space-separated sequence of values of VAR for
>   each iteration.  This can even be the output of a command if TOKENS
>   is replaced with `{ command invocation }'.

For your particular problem you have to remember that some commands have been replaced with eshell internals, including `kill`.  If you can't kill a process with

```
for pid in { ps -ef | grep "chrome" | awk '{print $2}' } {kill $pid}
```

try this instead

```
for pid in { ps -ef | grep "chrome" | awk '{print $2}' } {/usr/bin/kill $pid}
```

Or possibly better:

```
for pid in { pgrep "chrome" } {/usr/bin/kill $pid}
```

Comment: I tried `for pid in { ps -ef | grep "chrome" | awk '{print $2}' } {kill $pid}`;unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: You need `grep "chrome" -` in the pipe here.  See also http://www.masteringemacs.org/article/complete-guide-mastering-eshell for more eshell information.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I tried `grep "chrome" -` and it doesn't work.

Comment: When you say "unfortunately it doesn't work", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Nick: see my updated answer for something that ought to work.

Comment: On my system, kill is `/bin/kill`, both of your command works well. Thank you. (`pgrep` is really nice)