# how to do command substitution in eshell generally (NOT just for loop)

Tags: eshell, subprocess, find-dired

How to do command substitution à la Bash in Eshell, and **not** just for loops? (Unfortunately, while [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5723/5444) asks my question, its answer only provides Eshell `for`-loop syntax. So please don't dupe me with that: I seek an answer to the general question, using the example below.) FWIW,

- I'm a longtime Basher trying to learn Eshell. I like to think I'm Bash-strong (at least, I've been using it forever both at commandline and for scripts) but ...
- ... I know I'm Elisp-weak. I've adapted or written a few functions for my `init.el` and do some `C-u M-:` in buffers, but that's about it.
- I'm running Emacs on a Linux.

For this usecase, I want to look at all the *Office docs in a particular filetree

1. *sorted by time* (required)
2. in a Dired buffer (preferred)

Let the filetree root=`~/foo/bar/`. I can satisfy condition 2 with `find-name-dired`, but not condition 1: when I do

```
M-x find-name-dired ~/foo/bar/ *.odt
```

and then press `s` in the resulting buffer, I get the error

```
Cannot sort this Dired buffer
```

So I think, "I know how to do this in Bash. Perhaps if I do it in Eshell, that will give me a Dired buffer?" So I do

```
M-x eshell
```

but get

```
Welcome to the Emacs shell

~/foo/bar $ ls -alt $(find . -name '*.odt')
Invalid read syntax: ". in wrong context"
```

I assume that's a Lispism, and instead try

```
~/foo/bar $ ls -alt $(find ./ -name '*.odt')
Invalid read syntax: ")"
```

I've tried escaping the {parentheses, round brackets} various ways, and even backticks (note to reader--**don't use backticks** :-) to no avail: I either get the `Invalid read syntax: ")"` or more catastrophic errors. I then tried various sorts of `C-h` and websearch, without success. What am I doing wrong, and how to fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I then tried various sorts of C-h and websearch, without success.

Please check the manual first! (or second, after docstrings) [(eshell) Dollars Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eshell/Dollars-Expansion.html):

> ```
> Eshell has different ‘$’ expansion syntax from other shells.  There are
> some similarities, but don’t let these lull you into a false sense of
> familiarity.
> [...]
> ‘${command}’
>      Returns the output of ‘command’, which can be any valid Eshell
>      command invocation, and may even contain expansions.
> ```

So `ls -alt ${find . -name '*.odt'}` should work.  However,

> So I think, "I know how to do this in Bash. Perhaps if I do it in Eshell, that will give me a Dired buffer?"

It will not.

Comment: `ls -alt ${find . -name '*.odt'} should work.` It does, thanks.